# Node.JS: Session not saved in the middleware

Tags: node.js, session, middleware

I tried to make simple application with login and middleware.

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('./services/CORS.service');
const authorization = require('./middleware/auth');

const loginRouter = require('./login/login.routes');
const usersRouter = require('./users/users.routes');

const app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(cors);

app.use('/login', loginRouter);
app.use('/users', authorization, usersRouter);

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node app is running in: http://localhost:${PORT} ..`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

like you can see, I have login router and users with middleware router.

This is the loginRouter:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const _ = require('lodash');
const cryptoService = require('../services/crypto/service');

router.post('/login', login);

async function login(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const { account, session } = await controller.login(req.body);
        if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
            throw { message: 'Missing BasicAuth user and password', status: 400 };
        }

        const encryptedPassword = cryptoService.encrypt(password);

        const toEncrypt = JSON.stringify({username: username, password: encryptedPassword, timestamp: new Date()});
        const session = cryptoService.encrypt(toEncrypt);

        res.status(200).send({ session });
    }
    catch (err) {
        const errMessage = _.get(err, 'message', 'error occurred');
        const errCode = _.get(err, 'status', 500);
        res.status(errCode).json({ message: 'error occurred', error: errMessage });
    }
}

module.exports = router;
```

and this is the middleware:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const cryptoService = require('../services/crypto/service');
const moment = require('moment');
const SESSION_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_MINUTES = 50;

module.exports = async function (req, res, next) {

  try {
    const session = _.get(req, 'headers.session');
    console.log(session);
    let decryptedSession = '';

    try {
      decryptedSession = cryptoService.decrypt(session);
    }
    catch (err) {
      throw { message: 'Session is not valid, please re-login', status: 401 };
    }

    if (!decryptedSession) {
      throw { message: 'No session provided, please re-login', status: 401 };
    }
    const { username, password, timestamp } = JSON.parse(decryptedSession);

    if (!timestamp || moment.duration(moment().diff(timestamp)).asMinutes() > SESSION_TOKEN_EXPIRATION_IN_MINUTES) {
      throw { message: 'Session expired, please re-login', status: 401 };
    }
    res.locals = res.locals || {};
    res.locals.account = account;

    next();
  }
  catch (err) {
    const errMessage = _.get(err, 'message', 'error occurred');
    const errCode = _.get(err, 'status', 500);

    res.status(errCode).json({ message: 'error occurred during auth validation', error: errMessage });
  }

};
```

when the application running, I sending postman post request to login with username and password in the body.
I got a correct session.
but when I open the users page I got error:

```
No session provided, please re-login
```

because the session in the middleware is undefined.

what can I do to fix this code?
tnx

Comment: Did you find why cryptoServices doesn't return decrypted session?

Comment: I wrote it... session variable is undefined. @SergeyBerezovskiy

Comment: Ok, so make sure you have session header in your request

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy what does it mean? when i do post request the session returned in the body.